Magento 2 checkout call custom javascript AFTER order summary block loaded/reloaded
I want to run some javascript code every time the order summary block is loaded/re-loaded.
I am unsure of the best way to do this. I could override the get-totals.js file, but is there a way to subscribe to this event and have some javascript logic run when it is loaded/refreshed?

If you can't find any client-side events it would fire for this specifically (have you checked the docs?), then an implementation using a MutationObserver would be an alternative.

This event looks promising:
totals.getItems().subscribe

I was able to achieve what I wanted by subscribing to a method in the checkout totals javascript class.
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
totals.getItems().subscribe(function (items) {
                
}.bind(this));

